# Chrome browser: Blank white band below address bar occupies 5% of height

Tags: google-chrome

I using Chrome Version 112.0.5615.138 (Official Build) (32-bit) on Windows 10.  The update is "managed".  At the top of every webpage, I see a white band of wasted space just below the address bar, occupying about 5% of the height of my laptop screen.  I can find nothing like it from a Google search.

What is the band for?  How can I get rid of it?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Go to a website, press Ctrl-D then enter. Does something appear on that bar?

Comment: @Daniel B: You're right.  I don't normally use Chrome, so I have no bookmarks.  I disabled visibility of the bookmark bar and it is now gone.  Thanks!  Did you want to post the answer?

Comment: @Gantendo: Nothing happens when I press Ctrl+D.

Comment: @user2153235 That keycombo usually creates a bookmark.

Comment: @Gantendo: That's weird.  It didn't do anything before, but now it pops down a small menu save a bookmark.  But it's default to "Other bookmarks" rather than the bookmark toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it could be the bookmarks bar, without any bookmarks in it. With bookmarks it, looks like this:

[image: Chrome bookmarks bar]

You can toggle the bookmarks bar from the menu under *Bookmarks* → *Show bookmarks bar* or in *Settings* → *Appearance* or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (on Windows).